# how do I shrink texture in blender?

Tags: texturing

What I mean is that, sometimes when I apply textures like cotton fabric to gloves, it is applied quite a bit zoomed in, but I want the texture to be looked from far away so that the details are not noticed.

I would probably figure it out by myself when I just stack the square texture like 4x4 on the painting program and export it as one. But I would like to know if I can do that inside blender.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple options of doing what you are asking for.

**First option** (I'd recommend this one):

You can do this by adding a mapping node and the tweak the Scale values.
The UV texture coordinate is just an example. You can use any input you want, the scaling value will apply for all.

[image]

**Second option**:

When you unwrap an object you can go to the UV/image editor.
Select all faces you want to have a bigger/smaller tiling size and press 'S' to scale the UV's to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

You would do this using a [Mapping node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/render/blender_render/materials/nodes/types/vector/mapping.html)

You need to add a Texture Coordinate node, plug this into a Mapping node, and plug that into the Vector input for your Image Texture node.

You can then scale the texture by adjusting the three scale values in the Mapping node.